# I have to update 40 million rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code shown here is taking a very long time to update or populate 42673844. Could anyone help me on how to simplify this code and improve the performance.

I am trying to populate the Session ID's based on some conditions

Declaration of variables

```
declare @sval as INT
declare @maxRow as INT
declare @currvlt as int
declare @prevvlt as int
declare @cashamount as int
declare @sec as INT
declare @next_action as INT
declare @previous_action as INT
declare @rec as int
declare @currentRow as INT

-- assigning the maximum value to the @maxrow

set @maxRow = (select max(number) from dbo.stage3 as count)
print @maxRow

set @sval = 0

set @currentRow = 1

I am putting the conditions in a while loop to perform an update all the 42 million rows. The below select will assign the values to the declared variables

While (@currentRow <= @maxRow)
  begin
    select 
       @currvlt = vltid ,  
       @prevvlt = previous_vltid , 
       @cashamount = isnull(playercashableamount,0),
       @sec = seconds, 
       @next_action = next_action ,  --next record type
       @previous_action = previous_action,
       @rec = recordtype
    from dbo.stage3 
    where number = @currentRow
    
    if @currvlt <> @prevvlt or @prevvlt is null 
    begin
       update dbo.stage3 set sessionid = @sval+1 where number = @currentRow
       set @sval = @sval +1 
    end
    else
        if (@rec = '4' and @sec  > 30 and @previous_action in( 1 ,5)) or 
           (@cashamount < 1 and @sec  < 30 and @next_action in( 1 ,4 )) or 
           ((@rec = '5' and @sec < 30 and @next_action = '4' ) or  
             @next_action = '4')
        begin
           update dbo.stage3 set sessionid = @sval where number = @currentRow 
        end
        else 
           update dbo.stage3 set sessionid = @sval where number = @currentRow
   set @currentRow = @currentRow +1
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? We shouldn't need to infer your intent from code.

Comment: Hi, that has to be slow. Iterating row by row will be slow, especially for such big number of rows. What you need to do is to rewrite this whole logic to one update statement, if possible. We could help you most likely with that when you'll provide https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the suggestion and sorry for the inconvenience cased,  will do it right now

Comment: I have table stage 3 that contains all the below set of columns below is the select

Comment: Suggest you first format your code so that you (and everyone else) can actually see the structure of your nesting. Also, you use BEGIN/END excessively - no good reason to wrap a single statement with them as you do inside the loop. Putting a statement immediately after `ELSE` and on the same line makes reading your code more difficult. And it seems that last nested IF/ELSE logic is unnecessary since both branches to exactly the same thing.

Comment: But it seems that your code is just assigning a sequential "group number" (sessionid) based on vltid. But there seems to be a significant assumption about ordering of rows based on number (the column).

Comment: vltid previous_vltid transactionid recordtype transactiontime playercashableamount seconds previous_action next_action number sessionid
145726 145724 759944 5 2020-12-03 14:42:52 0 974 4 5 1 1
145728 145726 1302515 5 2020-12-03 14:26:38 0 1822 5 5 2 2
145728 145728 1302921 5 2020-12-03 14:57:01 0 276597 5 4 3 2
145736 145728 2487537 4 2020-12-06 19:46:57 0 58 5 4 4 3
145740 145736 1566895 4 2020-12-06 19:46:00 0 93 4 4 5 4
145740 145740 1566907 4 2020-12-06 19:47:32 0 176 4 4 6 4
145740 145740 1566941 4 2020-12-06 19:50:29 0 252 4 4 7 4

Comment: I have to populate the session id's based on the conditions i have used in the query

Comment: i have added the sample rows and similarly i have 40 million rows where i have to update or populate the session id's

Comment: Edit your post and add clarification to it - preferably as DDL and DML statements. As it stands, it is unlikely that anyone will attempt to help without more information about what the logic does and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have edited my post

Comment: please let me know if you need more information

Comment: You've changed the code multiple times at this point. No one can advise based off these multiple changes.  One query had top, now it's gone and replaced with this while loop query.  I would advise researching lock escalation to determine if you're locking the entire table and no one can help you if you keep changing the question.

Comment: Closed due to the question changing, and there being too many unknown aspects to reasonably answer. That said, do it in chunks of about 10000-100000 rows at a time, perhaps using ranges of IDs. Your problem is likely you are hitting your log high water mark - 40M updates in one transaction is unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. You should not need to do a row by row evaluation. Instead, address the entire set in one call when possible. Since you have provided no information about the business challenge you are trying to solve, this code is posted *as-is*. This may not be exactly what you're after, but it should get you going in the right direction. Please adjust for your own needs.

Also, any update on a table with 40 million rows will take a long time; even if you have perfectly tuned indexes on lightning fast storage. Instead of thinking "how do I get the answer I want?", try thinking "what am I asking the server to do for me?", and "is there a better way to make this request?" SQL Server runs best when dealing with a set of data in one pass. Analyzing row by row is not what the engine is built to do. It can be done, but should be used only when all other means have been exhausted.

The code below is a select statement. Run it, and if the results are what you're looking for, uncomment the UPDATE section, then comment out the SELECT section and run it.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN recordtype = '4'
                 AND seconds > 30
                 AND previous_action IN (1, 4) THEN 0
            WHEN s.cash_amount < 1
                 AND seconds < 30
                 AND next_action IN (1, 4) THEN 0
            WHEN next_action = 4 THEN 0
            WHEN (vltid <> previous_vltid)
                 OR previous_vltid IS NULL THEN s.RowNum
            ELSE s.RowNum
        END AS session_id
        ,s.vltid
        ,s.previous_vltid
        ,s.cash_amount
        ,s.recordtype
        ,s.previous_action
        ,s.seconds
        ,s.next_action
--UPDATE    s
--SET       sessionid = CASE
--                      WHEN recordtype = '4'
--                           AND seconds > 30
--                           AND previous_action IN (1, 4) THEN 0
--                      WHEN s.cash_amount < 1
--                           AND seconds < 30
--                           AND next_action IN (1, 4) THEN 0
--                      WHEN next_action = 4 THEN 0
--                      WHEN (vltid <> previous_vltid)
--                           OR previous_vltid IS NULL THEN s.RowNum
--                      ELSE s.RowNum
--                  END
FROM    (
            SELECT  sessionid
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vltid
                                        ORDER BY
                                            vltid
                                       ) AS RowNum
                    ,vltid
                    ,previous_vltid
                    ,ISNULL(playercashableamount, 0) AS cash_amount
                    ,recordtype
                    ,previous_action
                    ,seconds
                    ,next_action
            FROM    dbo.stage3
        ) AS s;
```